# Duplication vs. Tailwind Variants: Finding the Right Balance

Tags: frontend, tailwind-css, tailwind-variants

I'm facing a dilemma about component customization.

- When is it appropriate to create [Tailwind Variants](https://www.tailwind-variants.org/)?
- When does code duplication become more advantageous?
- What are the pros and cons of each approach?
- Is [Tailwind Merge](https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge) an alternative?

I might end up generating many different classes for a single component, which could go against Tailwind's philosophy of keeping CSS clear and concise. On the other hand, duplicating code to create component variations seems like an alternative, but it can lead to redundancy and complex maintenance.

> I'm looking forward to hearing your experiences and insights on avoiding overengineering in projects with Tailwind CSS. Thanks in advance!